# Transip API domain check failed to load external entity

Tags: php, soap, wsdl, openssl, plesk

I rent a VPS server at Transip.nl.
Auto install CentOS + Plesk 11.

They have an API that you can use to check if domain names are available. 
https://www.transip.nl/domeinnaam-en-webhosting/api/

I've installed everything correctly but now it's giving me an error:

> An error occurred: SOAP-ERROR: Parsing WSDL: Couldn't load from 'https://api.transip.nl/wsdl/?service=DomainService' : failed to load external entity "https://api.transip.nl/wsdl/?service=DomainService"

What is it that I have to do?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it! It was in the 'SELinux status'.

When I checked it with the command 'getenforce' on the server, it was displaying 'enforcing'. So I did: 'setenforce 0' and now it's working fine!

Thanks it you have looked for an answer to my question!